# .Css() function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, css

currently i am facing one problem in my code snippet where i am retrieving image url from css file based on image code where image code comes from another website
    and again another function takes image code as an argument make it as css class.

Based on the css class using .css() in jquery to retrieve the image url but when page initially loads it is returning "undefined" after some seconds it is returning correct image urls:

**JS function making image code as css class:**

```
$scope.placeholderNetworkImage = function(networkBenefitIcon){
    var selectorClassName = "."+ networkBenefitIcon;
    var blnResult = false;

     if(networkBenefitIcon!=="null" && networkBenefitIcon!=="")
     {

        var imagePresent = $(selectorClassName).css('backgroundImage');
        console.log("image of url is: "+imagePresent);
        if (imagePresent == 'none' || imagePresent == null) {
           blnResult = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            blnResult = false;
        }
     }
    else
    {
       blnResult = true;
    }
       return blnResult;
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="media-left">
  <ul>
    <li class="networkBenefitIconLi" ng-repeat="networkBenefitIcon in 
           item.t_css_tariffBenefit.split('|') track by $index | limitTo:3">
      <span ng-class="networkBenefitIcon" class="networkBenefitIcon" ng-
                   show="!placeholderNetworkImage(networkBenefitIcon)">
          </span>
      <span class="networkBenefitIcon tickLightGray" ng-
                    show="placeholderNetworkImage(networkBenefitIcon)">
          </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

output:

[it was output shown on console here you can find some were image url's and some are showing "undefined"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9gil.png)

Kindly help me with this problem as it was a huge performance issue form our side.please any one tell me why it was returning "undefined" even though image was present in the css.

Comment: `networkBenefitIcon!=="null"` looks wrong to me.

Comment: Please dont attach screenshots of errors. Instead paste them as code- or quote-blocks.

Comment: Another logic issue: In that if, `blnResult = false;` is always going to set it to false.... There is no reason to set it to false when the default is false.

Comment: If the selector does not find the element, it will be undefined. Is that the case here? `console.log(selectorClassName, $(selectorClassName).length);`

Comment: Then try excuting your code within an onload event handler

Comment: CSS doesn't have a `backgroundImage` property. Do you mean `background-image`?

Comment: @Santi unrelated. both are valid and do the same.

Comment: @KevinB Hmmm. https://jsfiddle.net/z49oa01h/ What am I doing wrong? **EDIT:** Got it. https://jsfiddle.net/z49oa01h/1/ for anyone else curious! Thanks Kevin.

Comment: @epascarello actually why blnResult = false; because I have written ng-
                   show="!placeholderNetworkImage(networkBenefitIcon)" in html code thus !(false) is always true.

Comment: @epascarello it is returning undefined for every image code irrespective of the element is present or not elements presents and undefined for no elements.But after some seconds it will return correct urls.

Comment: @BaluChindanur no the logic inside will always be false... `blnResult` will never be true because of the blnResult = false; outside of the if/else

Answer (score -1):

I think you already have the answer. First, wait until the DOM is ready! 
Then, get the background image URL (edited the answer and left a snippet to show evidence):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  function getImageBackgroundUrl ($el) {
    var imgUrl = $el.css('backgroundImage')
    return imgUrl
  }

  function doSomething (imgUrl) {
    console.log('imgUrl is', imgUrl)
  }

  var images = $('.my-images ul li');
  $.each(images, function (k, v) {
      var $el = $(v)
      var imgUrl = getImageBackgroundUrl($el)      
      doSomething(imgUrl)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.a {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/200/305?2)
}
.b {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/200/305?3)
}
.c {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/200/305?4)
}
</style>
<div class="my-images">
  <ul>
    <li class="a"></li>
    <li class="b"></li>
    <li class="c"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```